# Custom map tiles not loading -- Leafletjs

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I am following a tutorial on how to create your own custom map. I sliced my image into tiles, but nothing loads when I go to view the page.

The JavaScript:

```
L.tileLayer('/Users/ranichd/Desktop/maptest/{z}_{x}_{y}.png', {
    minZoom: 1,
    maxZoom: 6,
    attribution: 'David'
}).addTo(map);
```

The CSS:

```
#carpmap2 {
    height: 400px;
    width: 900px;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

A screenshot of the map tiles:

[image: http://imgur.com/SrQewWA]

And finally, the result I am getting:

[image: http://imgur.com/FV9jtIA]

How can I make this work?

Answer (score 1):

Your tiles have to be served by an [http server](https://httpd.apache.org/).

```
L.tileLayer('http://yourhost/maptest/{z}_{x}_{y}.png', {
    minZoom: 1,
    maxZoom: 6,
    attribution: 'David'
}).addTo(map);
```

Comment: Not necessarily - tiles can be served from a [`file:/` path](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_URI_scheme), or from a path relative to the webpage. While the problem may be due to a lack of control over which path the images are finally being fetched from, the solution is not restricted to serving them from an absolute `http://` path.

Comment: So how would you recommend I go about doing so through a file path? I tried doing the full file path, which can be seen above, so I'm really lost.

Comment: you can try adding the file URI scheme. file://Users/ranichd/Desktop/maptest/{z}_{x}_{y}.png. Also look at your browser console log to have details about the error.

Comment: By the way, if it is on Windows you will have to add the disk letter: file:///c:/Users

Comment: I apologize, I should've stated this but I am using a mac. Unfortunately using 'file://Users/ranichd/Desktop/maptest/{z}_{x}_{y}.png' didn't work either. And upon checking the console, I saw this: [link](http://imgur.com/sfKWmCM)

Comment: You will have to change your browser security settings to allow loading local resources. I would advise to setup a web server though.

Comment: @FranceImage: I have been having a hard time finding a way to allow local resources; a lot of the information I found no longer works. I agree I will eventually want to get a web server, but I don't need to have one right now (I may be contradicting myself, because I may end up having to do so if I don't find a fix).

Maybe I should've given more context:

I am working on making indoor maps for the various schools in the district I work in (I'm a technology person for the school system in my state) and am working on one map at a time.